# Filter list as a parameter in a compiled query

Tags: entity-framework, linq.compiledquery

I have the following compiled query that I want to  return a list of "groups" that don't have a "GroupID" that's contained in a filtered list:

```
CompiledQuery.Compile(ConfigEntities contexty, List<int> list) =>
    from c in context.Groups
    where (!csList.Contains(c.GroupID))
    select c).ToList()
```

However I'm getting the following run-time error:

> The specified parameter 'categories' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c261364e126]]' is not valid. Only scalar parameters (such as Int32, Decimal, and Guid) are supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will work fine in EF 4.

In EF 1, `IEnumerable.Contains` isn't supported in L2E (with or without `CompiledQuery`). There is a workaround, though; Google "BuildContainsExpression`, or [look here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/where-in-clause?forum=adodotnetentityframework).

Comment: Yeah just been having a look at that as well, but I'm still getting the same error message. Any ideas why?

Comment: If it's *exactly* the same message, then you're not using EF 4. If it's a different message, then post it and the actual query you're using. The message you posted doesn't actually conform to the query in your question, so I suspect there's some editing going on.

Comment: Wait; i need to use EF4 for the BuildsContainsExpression?

Exact query is:
            _compiledRefreshListGraphQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile((DASConfigEntities context, List<int> cSList) =>
                                                                   context.Groups.
                                                                       Where(ObjectQueryExt.BuildContainsExpression<Group, int>(e => e.GroupID, cSList)));

Comment: Other way around. EF 4 doesn't require `BuildContainsExpression` at all. It's only needed in EF 1.

Comment: Yeah so I'm using EF1, with the BuildContainsExpression (copied and pasted) with the precompiled query as above - but I'm getting exactly the same error message.

Comment: Then you're not using it correctly. Build the expression first, then do `.Where(builtExpression)`

Comment: How would that be possible with pre-compiled queries though?
The precompiled query takes cSList, as does the BuildContainsExpression. Perhaps it's time just to use 4.0

Comment: Contains is not supported in EF4 for compiled queries, which makes sense given this argument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787330/compiledquery-with-list-contains-where-in-list-functionality/3787363#3787363.